# Can't install Moles in Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, moles

I'm trying to install [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) (without Pex, since Pex is only available for free for non-commercial purposes) using the downloads found [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b3b41648-1c21-471f-a2b0-f76d8fb932ee/) (that's the x86 version, I've tried the x64 version as well).

The installer(s) run without errors, and inform me that Moles have been installed correctly. But when I start Visual Studio, I see no trace that this add-in should be installed. It doesn't show up among the installed extensions in Extension manager, and I can't add any Moles items into my projects.

Is there some installation step that I'm missing here?

Comment: As far as I remember, Moles will **not** show up in **Extension Manager** (it is a VS 2010 goodness which many plugins don't support).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if moles is installed go to:

--> Help --> About Microsoft Visual Studio

If it is in the list, it is installed. To use moles you have to create a test project and go to the reference in the test project you want to mole. Right click and Add Moles Assembly.

I see some posts of VS.NET SP1 with moles. So installing is possible.

Comment: Ha! It turns out that Moles was installed after all =) What threw me off was that going to the assembly and selecting "Add moles assembly" isn't at all the way they do it in some [screencasts](http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/170)...

Comment: It seems this question was solved. I have some follow-up questions (since I'm still stuck) but I figured they were so independent of this that they merited [their own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569956/moles-adding-assembly-to-wrong-project). Feel free to take a look at it =)