# Moles adding assembly to wrong project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, moles

I'm trying to get started with [Microsoft Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) in order to be able to mock my extension methods, but I'm falling short.

I've successfully installed Moles on my workstation, but when I go to my test project (a class library project referencing NUnit, not an MSTest project), navigate down through References, right-click the assembly I want to stub (NHibernate in this case) and click "Add moles assembly...", the NHibernate.moles file shows up in an entirely different project in my solution. It's only content is

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/">
  <Assembly Name="NHibernate" />
</Moles>
```

This doesn't seem to get me anywhere. I expected to be able to follow [this screencast](http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/170) from Dime Casts to get started, but I don't have the "Moles and Stubs for Testing" item template shown in the screencast.

I don't seem to be able to get anywhere from here. What do I need to do to get those templates? And why does the moles "assembly" end up in the wrong project? How do I proceed from here to be able to start using Moles?

Comment: The content of the file is configuration for moles. There should be a NHibernate.Moles assembly in your references.

Comment: @peer: I get no NHibernate.Moles assembly - not in the project in which I chose "Add Moles Assembly", and not in the (other) project where the config file is added.

Comment: If you compile do you see something like: 'Generation x Moles assemblies in x concurrent process' ? I have added the Moles assemblies in my test project.

Answer (score 0):

The mole assemblies don't show up at the beginning in your References folder. Build the project, click "Show All Files" and you'll see a MolesAssemblies folder containing your generated Mole assemblies.